# Perform a lookup between C# Lists and return matched where value is minimum

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two lists:

```
var qtys = new List<InventoryQuantity>()
{
    new InventoryQuantity() { WarehouseId = 1, QuantityInWarehouse = 0 },
    new InventoryQuantity() { WarehouseId = 2, QuantityInWarehouse = 452 },
    new InventoryQuantity() { WarehouseId = 3, QuantityInWarehouse = 184 },
    new InventoryQuantity() { WarehouseId = 4, QuantityInWarehouse = 328 },
    new InventoryQuantity() { WarehouseId = 5, QuantityInWarehouse = 0 },
};

var times = new List<WarehouseTransitTime>()
{
    new WarehouseTransitTime() { WarehouseId = 1, TransitDays = 1 },
    new WarehouseTransitTime() { WarehouseId = 2, TransitDays = 4 },
    new WarehouseTransitTime() { WarehouseId = 3, TransitDays = 2 },
    new WarehouseTransitTime() { WarehouseId = 4, TransitDays = 3 },
    new WarehouseTransitTime() { WarehouseId = 5, TransitDays = 5 },
};

class InventoryQuantity
{
    public int WarehouseId { get; set; }
    public int QuantityInWarehouse { get; set; }
}

class WarehouseTransitTime
{
    public int WarehouseId { get; set; }
    public int TransitDays { get; set; }
}
```

I need to return the WarehouseId from qtys where the Quantity > 0 and the WarehouseId equals the minimum transit days WarehouseId in times.

I know I can do something like below but seems clunky and there must be an elegant solution.

```
    public int NearestWarehouse()
    {
        var withQty = qtys.Where(i => i.QuantityInWarehouse > 0);
        var orderedTransit = times.OrderBy(tt => tt.TransitDays).ToList();
        //loop and compare
    }
```

Example data:

qtys

```
WarehouseId | Quantity
1           | 0
2           | 452
3           | 184
4           | 328
5           | 0
```

times

```
WarehouseId | TransitTime
1           | 1
2           | 4
3           | 2
4           | 3
5           | 5
```

Expected output would be 3, because warehouse 3 has inventory and the shortest transit time (2)

Comment: Can you share an example data and expected result from it?

Comment: Does `WarehouseId` the same in both lists in the same order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the cleanest and simplest query is this:

```
var query =
    from q in qtys
    where q.QuantityInWarehouse > 0
    join t in times on q.WarehouseId equals t.WarehouseId
    orderby t.TransitDays
    select q.WarehouseId;

var warehouseId = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

This gives me `3`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a [group join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.8):

*Functional Syntax*

```
var query1 = qtys.Where(q => q.QuantityInWarehouse > 0)
                 .GroupJoin(times, q => q.WarehouseId, t => t.WarehouseId, (q, t) => new { q.WarehouseId, TransitDays = t.DefaultIfEmpty().Min(grp => grp?.TransitDays) })
                 .OrderBy(g => g.TransitDays)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

*Query Syntax*

```
var query2 = from q in qtys
             join t in times on q.WarehouseId equals t.WarehouseId into grp
             where q.QuantityInWarehouse > 0
             select new
             {
                 q.WarehouseId,
                 TransitDays = grp.DefaultIfEmpty().Min(g => g?.TransitDays)
             };

var result = query2.OrderBy(g => g.TransitDays)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

A group join will join two lists together on their corresponding keys--similar to a database join--and the associated values to those keys will be grouped into an enumerable. From that enumerable, you can derive the minimum value that you care about, `TransitDays` in this case.

There is no equivalent to "first or default" in query syntax. The easiest approach is just to apply the same `OrderBy` and `FirstOrDefault` against the query variable, as demonstrated above.

Comment: The answer is pretty fair but in your *query syntax* please explain to me: is this `q.WarehouseId` in **{ }** respects the call to `grp.Min()`? (I mean it doesn't just select a random id, right?) Is the code in **{ }** executes when *grp* is empty? Than consider using `?.` also before `Min()`.

Comment: @Alb Why would it pick a random ID? The grouping happens on the IDs, just like a SQL join would. Imagine you have a bag of different colored and sized marbles. You take a marble from the bag one at a time. Each marble you pick gets put into a pile of the same color. Now you have `n` number of piles of marbles, where each pile is keyed by color. Now you look for the smallest marble in each pile. Picking the smallest marble from any one pile doesn't change its color (i.e. key).

Comment: So you assume there is more than 1 WarehouseTransitTime object exists with the same ID. Not bad. Though in this case your answer is - according to question - misses the `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` command in the *Functional Syntax* part and the corresponding command in the *Query Syntax* part! :)

Comment: @Alb Why would I need `FirstOrDefault` if I'm using `Min`?

Comment: You just said you return the *Min* **for each ID** ("smallest marble in each pile"). So, you return a List/IEnumerable. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, `query2` is an `IEnumerable`, specifically `IEnumerable<{int, int}>` (syntax mine to denote it's an anonymous object in the IEnumerable). The same way you would have, after your selections, a collection of marbles, where each marble has a color (code) and size (i.e. {int, int}).

Comment: As OP requested, he wants the WarehouseId (note the singular noun) where the `q.WarehouseId > 0` and `TransitTime` is the lowest! It is more clear if you take a look at his edit part (*Example Data: ...*). I upvoted your answer because I think your `GroupJoin` is better than my `key.Contains`, though, please fix this. `.FirstOrDefault().WharehousId` is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Well you mention an AND relation between the two, right?

I was thinking of databases with a forignkey... but Linq prety much does it if your lists aren't to big:

```
keys = qtys.Where(i => i.QuantityInWarehouse > 0).Select(i => i.WarehouseId).ToList();
// get the smallest not a list
var result = times.Where(tt => keys.Contains(tt.wharehouseId)).orderby(tt => tt.Transitdays).FirstOrDefault();
```

Otherwise you could have `Dictionary` with ID as key...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this..

```
   var withQty = (from q in qtys
                       join t in times on q.WarehouseId equals t.WarehouseId
                       where q.QuantityInWarehouse > 0
                       select new { q.WarehouseId, t.TransitDays })
                       .OrderBy(item => item.TransitDays).FirstOrDefault();


   return withQty?.WarehouseId ?? 0;
```

Comment: I'm getting an Object Reference error when qtys contains exactly one element where the quantity > 0

Comment: I tried with only qtys.Add(new InventoryQuantity { WarehouseId = 2, QuantityInWarehouse = 452 });, it worked w/o any object reference error

Comment: To handle case when there is no qty where quantity > 0, changed .First() to .FirstOrDefault()